# Spring injection in xml using add method

Tags: spring

I would like to inject one bean into another using an `addProperty` method. For example, if I have bean `A` and bean `B` and bean `B` has a method `addA()` but not setter method, how do I inject bean `A` into `B` without resorting to annotations.

Comment: What does `addA()` do? Does it add to a `List<A>`? If so does `List<A>` have a setter?

Comment: I think internally `addA()` adds `A` to some kind of collection but I have no idea what it is doing. I have no access to source of the library but the library is full of APIs like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<bean id="a" class="my.A" />

<bean id="b" class="my.B" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="b" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="addA" />
    <property name="arguments" ref="a" />
</bean>
```

Of course, this approach doesn't scale well if you've got a lot of bean-wiring to do. If you own the code, you should use Spring annotations and auto-wiring, or define setters and use the 'property' Spring XML tags.

Comment: At least I can use it to load the some beans at startup. Thanks for your help, @bcody.